# Azure B2C - change sign in - token returns old email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have taken the change sign in example (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/change-sign-in-name) and added this into my custom policy files. If I run through this process and change the user's email address, then the value in B2C's AD is updated to the new email address, however the value in the returned token is still the user's old email address before they updated it.

However I want to return the new email address that the user entered back to the application. Is this possible?

My code:

Relying Party:

```
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="ChangeSignInName" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

User Journey:

```
    <UserJourney Id="ChangeSignInName">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- To change the sign-in names, user need to sign-in with local account only -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted.changesignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Sign-in user with local account-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress2" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Read the user data from the Azure Active Directory -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This self asserted technical profile validates and update the sign-in name -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserSignInUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EmailUpdate" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

Technical Profiles:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress2">
          <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.changesignin</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>

            <!--OTP validation error messages-->
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionDoesNotExist">You have exceed the maximum time allowed.</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfMaxRetryAttempted">You have exceed the number of retries allowed.</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionConflict">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />

          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>


        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>

            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-EmailUpdate">
            <DisplayName>Email update</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.changesignin</Item>

        <!--OTP validation error messages-->
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionDoesNotExist">You have exceed the maximum time allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfMaxRetryAttempted">You have exceed the number of retries allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionConflict">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</Item>
            </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
           <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
        </CryptographicKeys>
            <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            </InputClaims>
      <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControlUpdateEmail" />
      </DisplayClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <!-- Collect and validate the email address -->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <!-- Call validation technical profile to persist the data-->
                <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteEmailUsingObjectId" />
            </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Azure AD User's object is updated correctly then most likely updated claim is not added to the claim's bag. To make things easier, do this test first and report the findings:

1. Add a new step right before the last step, making it step 5 and the last step will be step 6 as shown below:

```
  <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId_AfterUpdate" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

2. Run the policy, and confirm whether you do see an updated email or an old one? if you see the updated email then it means one of the technical profiles not emitting the output claim correctly.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and I still get the old email returned. When checking the Users in B2C, the email of the user does not update with the change until several seconds later, which I understand is expected behaviour.
Therefore, rather than querying the details of the user from AD after updating them, I think I just want to take the email value that the user has entered as pass this out at the end of the user journey.